# Configuring Jackson's ObjectMapper through Grail's bean DSL

Tags: spring, grails, jackson

I need a shared instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper in grails, so I think the most standard way to do it is through beans DSL.
I tried something like (with many variations, like using delegate keyword) in resources.groovy

```
objectMapper(ObjectMapper) { bean ->
    bean.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY)
    bean.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
}
```

but it didn't work, ObjectMapper is configured the default way, which doesn't work well with grails.
I used a workaround which does what I need (in BootStrap.groovy):

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def bean = Holders.applicationContext.objectMapper
    bean.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY)
    bean.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
}
```

Can anyone point me to how to do it in beans DSL, where it belongs (IMHO)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the *bean* closure parameter is of some subtype of [AbstractBeanDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition.html), it does not refer to the actual object instance itself.

There are various ways to set the visibility and configure the ObjectMapper instance:

- create a subclass and do the work in the constructor
- instantiate the ObjectMapper in a [factory (method)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class)
- write a [factory bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)
- ...

You can use all the Spring IoC container mechanisms for bean instantiation in Grails.

Not that I had that exact use-case, but I would tend to create a custom factory bean and put the logic for the ObjectMapper configuration there.

Comment: Thanks, subclassing seems good to me and simple enough (and it works).
If no one comes with a pure DSL solution I will accept this

Answer (score 1):

Provide [JsonFactory](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html) in the constructor instead of using the default constructor.

```
//resources.groovy
beans = {
    jf(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory)

    objectMapper(ObjectMapper, jf){
        visibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY)
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    }
}
```

This can be verified in console as:

```
assert grailsApplication.mainContext.objectMapper instanceof com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to work with grails 2.3 (didn't try earlier versions). It complains about 'bean' property not found; removing it results in default ObjectMappper

Comment: @RiccardoCossu Can you let me know which `ObjectMapper` you are referring to? Full package name of `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: just edited the question, my fault: it's com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: @RiccardoCossu Here, updated my answer according to your information.

Comment: works for some beans and not for other ones... for some beans it gives a JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class <FQCN of a class>.
That same class works ok with subclassing approach, I'm not sure what's the difference... +1 anyway, thanks

Comment: @RiccardoCossu I think Ian's is a better and appropriate approach except if you want to set the visibility explicitly you have to use the same way he has done for `configure` since `setVisibility` returns the `ObjectMapper` again.

Answer (score 1):

For the visibility bit, you could set a `VisibilityChecker` rather than using the convenience `setVisibility` method

```
vc(VisibilityChecker.Std, Visibility.ANY)

objectMapper(ObjectMapper) {
  visibilityChecker = ref('vc')
}
```

but the `configure` call is more difficult, you'd have to use a factory bean approach to call the method, defining a separate bean.  The point is that you don't want to call the methods yourself, rather you're trying to tell Spring what *it* needs to call when it wants to create the beans:

```
objectMapperConfig(objectMapper:'configure',
                     DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

Since configure returns a reference to the mapper itself, a better way to ensure the dependencies get resolved in the right order might be to say

```
vc(VisibilityChecker.Std, Visibility.ANY)

objectMapperUnconfigured(ObjectMapper) {
  visibilityChecker = ref('vc')
}

objectMapper(objectMapperUnconfigured:'configure',
                     DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

and then use `objectMapper` as the bean you inject into other places.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the reply, but I think that subclassing is the easiest and cleanest approach

Comment: @RiccardoCossu yes, I would think that subclassing and adding a `@PostConstruct public void init()` will be the cleanest approach.

Comment: agreed, but for my use writing that in the constructor is good enough :-)